# Potentiometer at 0 resistance + arduino = smoke

Tags: arduino, potentiometer

I had connected a pot to my arduino and i cross check the wiring before switch on. 
Everything went well but when I turned the pot to zero resistance, It started to release smoke and the arduino got disconnected .

When i turned the pot back to the other end, it got connected. (resistance = 10k ohm)

Now everything is working fine. But why did it happen?. What precaution should i take from next time?

Thank you

Comment: Zero resistance = short circuit. Don't do that. If you need to protect against someone doing that, put a fixed resistor in series with the potentiometer or don't connect it as a variable resistor (rheostat) connect it as a potentiometer.

Comment: You'll need to give more details on how it was connected. As a wild guess, were you trying to use the potentiometer as a voltage divider between power and ground, but connected power to the wiper instead of the end?  In that case, you'd get a short instead of the expected zero volt output which would overheat the potentiometer and shut off the Arduino. Precaution: check the potentiometer pinout with a multimeter first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the handy diagram below. Only RV1 is connected correctly- the other ones are connected in a way that will short the supply when the pot is at one end or the other.

Your pot has probably been traumatized by the experience and it may have a dead spot that is near the end where it smoked, somewhat similar to the dead spot one could get in one's vision from staring directly into a high power laser beam (not recommended).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHwO6E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>